# Show a div with the layout like a dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to format multiple containers (div) in a web page to look like a jquery-ui dialog.
The divs should automatically change if I change the theme.

So far I'm applying a jquery-ui tab to the div, but this don't have the same title bar and I need to add a lot of html for each div

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I create a little plugin for do that
http://jsbin.com/themedcontent/latest
@Neal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same css as jQuery UI and apply it to your divs.

Examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Fyj7L/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Fyj7L/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Fyj7L/2/

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez nooo problem ^_^